# End to end exactly-once sample code

Tags: flink-streaming

I'm new to Apache Flink streaming and want to implement end to end exactly-once. I read the following blog and got the main ideas (I know how it works): 
https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html

But I couldn't find any example (sample source code). Is there any source code of implementing end to end exactly-once using twoPhaseCommitSinkFunction
-thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `FlinkKafkaProducer011` implements the `TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction` and can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-0.11/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer011.java).